# How to completely delete a node in Cocos2d-js?

Tags: javascript, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-js

I have created a node with a sprite and when I use `child.removeFromParent()` on the node, although the node does disappear, I can still access to its contents such as the position of the sprite. I am worrying about what if I create many nodes and delete them immediately.

Would that cause a memory leak? Or how can I completely delete a node in `Cocos2d-js`?

Comment: isn't  `child` a reference to the node you are deleting ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think cocos use an intern gc so maybe the life of an object lasts a bit after removing. 
Also you can use retain/release to manually managing the object.
Retain when you create it and release when you delete it after a removeChild.

Answer (score 0):

Try removeFromParentAndCleanup(cleanup) instead

Comment: this is deprecated, child.removeFromParent(cleanup) should be the up to date function. [link] (http://www.cocos2d-x.org/reference/html5-js/V3.8/symbols/cc.Node.html#removeFromParentAndCleanup)